# How can i move files to a portable device using batch in windows7

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7-x64, mount, motorola

I'm using Motorola MC67 (I'm not sure that matter, but it's a portable device) and i want to write a batch script to move files there. the problem is i can't call the device path because it's not mounted and i can't mount it. i couldn't find nothing on google about getting to the device not from the windows GUI. I read somewhere activeSync can sync from portable devices, but that's of no use to me.
anyway, i repeat, i need a way to move files from my computer to a portable device that isn't mounted. a way to mount the device will be good too, since i can then access it from batch file

Comment: What do you exactly mean with `mount`, please?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows-vista/mount-or-dismount-a-drive

Comment: The first thing to know is if the device have _any_ physicall connection! USB? Accept memory cards? Any other one?

Comment: @Aacini USB physicall connection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to download [Windows Mobile Developer Power Toys](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10601) because it contains the `cecopy` utility, which this solution depends on.

Basically, all you need to do is:

```
cecopy file.exe dev:\file.exe
```

Here's the readme for cecopy.

```
INSTRUCTIONS:
Usage:  CeCopy  [options] <Source_FileSpec>  <Destination>

Options:

    /is                  Copy file even if identical.
    /s                   Include subdirectories, hierarchy reproduced on device.

Arguments:

    Source_FileSpec      File specification denoting the source of the copy.
    Destination          Where files should be copied to.

For the source, wild cards or directory names may be specified, as may be single files.  The destination can be either a directory or a file name, depending on the type of source specified.

By default, an argument is assumed to live on a local file system.  To indicate that either argument denotes a location on a device connected via ActiveSync, prepend 'dev:' to that argument.   To articulate that a local file system is referenced, prepend 'desk:' to the argument.

Examples:
"cecopy readme.txt dev:\readme.txt" copies this readme to the device's root.
"cecopy /s *.* dev:\" copies all files and subfolders of current directory to device's root.  Generates new folders on device as needed.
"cecopy /s *.dll dev:\windows" copies all dlls and dlls in subfolders of current directory to the device's root.  Generates new folders on device as needed.
```

Comment: Sir. Do you guess, the **Motorola Mobile Phone** device might have **Microsoft Windows Mobile** operating system?

Comment: @DanyBee Sorry, I don't understand your question. CECOPY doesn't depend on the device having Window Mobile. "CECopy - Command line tool for copying files to the device currently connected to desktop ActiveSync." Which is apparently what the asker needed.

Comment: The above Microsoft link is dead (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10601). As of August 2016, I am not able to find the cecopy tool from a reliable source. I have tried https://www.google.com/webhp?q=%22cecopy%22+mtp&tbs=qdr:y

Comment: @davidmneedham maybe it's included in some of the packages referenced here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb894407(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can't *mount* the device per se, but you can access it via the [Windows Portable Devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) api.  There are some application samples [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpdblog/archive/2009/09/25/windows-7-application-samples.aspx), but they're in C++.  There's a [scripting interface](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpdblog/archive/2009/08/21/introducing-wpd-automation.aspx), but that seems to be limited to the device stage experience, and doesn't really seem to be available from, say, Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

the total commander recognize the device and can be used to transfer files through it, and be used progrematicly